# PHP or Node.js for a tournament style poker app?

Tags: php, node.js, server-side, backend

I'm planning to build a tournament style poker app (ie only tournament play). My main experience is on a LAMP stack but the more I read about Node.js it seems like this would be a better language for this type of project. Which would be better php or node.js or will there not be a very significant difference? Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a lot of fancy real time interaction with Ajax/Comet and want to support a lot of concurrent connections, I think that Node.js would be worth learning. There would certainly be no downside to it! Personally, even though I'm a PHP programmer by trade, I hate using it for large or complex projects, and it wasn't exactly built to scale.

If you have any experience with JavaScript, give Node.js a try. Maybe you around with it for a couple of projects first to evaluate it and get comfortable.

Comment: There is one downside, and that is Node is a lot less forgiving than PHP. I've seen some pretty terrible PHP code which does horribly, horribly inefficient things, yet still chugs away with multiple concurrent users. The same sort of thing in node would queue up requests and everything would grind to a halt.

Comment: That's true. I think that in PHP you can get away with practically no knowledge of HTTP. With Node, some of the abstraction is taken away and, like you said, it is less forgiving. However, I believe that it is worth learning, especially if you already have a good grasp of JavaScript.